Render <button> as a text link in a paragraph, with wrapping / flow
I'd like to render a link-styled <button> within a paragraph of text and have it cleanly participate in the paragraph's line wrapping / text flow.
Styling the button isn't hard, and setting display: inline lets it participate in normal line wrapping / text flow - but only if the button is able to fit on one line of text. Otherwise, the button gets displayed on its own line.
In other words, I want what MDN calls a "line-split inline element."
(It would be far simpler to just turn the <button> into an <a> or a <span>, but that's bad for accessibility, and it's my understanding that modern HTML + CSS is supposed to give you enough control to not have to resort to such things.)
Here's what I've tried so far, with a demonstration of the issue.


.inline-button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
  line-height: inherit;
}

#narrow {
  width: 5em;
}
<p>
  This is a paragraph with <button class="inline-button">inline button</button> that wraps nicely with the text.
</p>

<div id="narrow">
  <p>
    This is a paragraph with <button class="inline-button">inline button</button> that wraps nicely with the text.
  </p>
</div>




What does the button do? Perhaps it's not the right element here. Modern html and css have come a long way but they are still not magic.

Especially if you describe it as a link?

Sorry, but what's the question here?

@Paulie_D - It shows / expands a text block of additional information, after the paragraph that it's in. It's styled as a link (because it's a piece of a larger paragraph of text, and links look nicer that way), but semantically, it's not a link (because it doesn't navigate to another page).

@j08691 - I want an inline <button> that participates in word wrapping and text flow just like other text does, instead of forcing a whole line to itself.

Hmm, fair but in this instance I think you might just have to go with a span with appropriate accessibility attributes to minimise any such issues. I'm on mobile at the moment but will research more later.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role

Looks like this has come up before. https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3226

Using an anchor <a> is totally accessible and probably more accurate if this appears in the text of a paragraph. Buttons are more for actions like previous, next, submit, edit, save, etc.

Since this does appear to be a slight limitation in current CSS and HTML, I ended up going with @Paulie_D's straightforward approach: a <span>, with appropriate CSS styling and HTML attributes (tabindex=0 role=button, plus responding to Enter / Space keys) to act like a link.

The only thing you can do is to use display: contents but you need to see about the accessibility issue that might happen doing this.


.inline-button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline; /* this won't work (and other properties as well) */
  cursor: pointer;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  display: contents;
  line-height: inherit;
}

#narrow {
  width: 5em;
}
<p>
  This is a paragraph with <button class="inline-button">inline button</button> that wraps nicely with the text.
</p>

<div id="narrow">
  <p>
    This is a paragraph with <button class="inline-button">inline button</button> that wraps nicely with the text.
  </p>
</div>




Thanks, @TemaniAfif. I had wondered about display: contents (and have used it elsewhere), although the fact that text-decoration: underline and other properties don't work seems like a significant drawback.
